# Concatenated cells with a conditional formatting adjustment

Tags: excel, formatting, string-concatenation, vba

I'm trying to concatenate two cells and format a substring based on the presence of a "U" in the string. I've viewed a couple of other threads to build the code below but it hangs up at the .characters command line.

The concatenation is also iterative based upon the value comparisons in the B, C and D columns being same. Will the red characters remain in place during successive concatenations or would i be better off trying to just format the final string based on the parts of the resultant string with a U in it?

If for example the H column values were to be joined together in the loop below in sequence as follows:

1. 7/11/2012 A & vbCrLf & 8/09/2014 A U
2. 7/11/2012 A & vbCrLf & 8/09/2014 A U & vbCrLf & 18/09/2013 A
3. 7/11/2012 A & vbCrLf & 8/09/2014 A U & vbCrLf & 18/09/2013 A & vbCrLf & 7/02/2014 A U

I'd really appreciate any assistance. TIA.

```
Sub CustomFormat()

' CustomFormat Macro


Dim LR As Long, Rw As Long, FinishPoint As Integer

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Rw = LR To 1 Step -1

    If Range("B" & Rw).Value = Range("B" & Rw - 1).Value And _
    Range("C" & Rw).Value = Range("C" & Rw - 1).Value And _
    Range("D" & Rw).Value = Range("D" & Rw - 1).Value Then
        Range("H" & Rw - 1).Value = Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value & vbCrLf & Range("G" &   Rw).Value
    End If

    If InStr(1, Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value, "U") Then
        FinishPoint = Len(Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value)
        With Range("H" & Rw - 1).Value
            With .Characters(1, FinishPoint).Font.Color = vbRed
            End With
        End With
    End If

Next Rw
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
Sub CustomFormat()
    Dim LR As Long, Rw As Long, i As Byte
    Dim FinishPoint As Integer, StartPoint As Integer

    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Rw = LR To 2 Step -1

        If Range("B" & Rw).Value = Range("B" & Rw - 1).Value And _
                Range("C" & Rw).Value = Range("C" & Rw - 1).Value And _
                Range("D" & Rw).Value = Range("D" & Rw - 1).Value Then

            Range("H" & Rw - 1).Value = Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value & vbCrLf & Range("G" & Rw).Value

            If InStr(1, Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value, "U") Then
                FinishPoint = Len(Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value)
                With Range("H" & Rw - 1)
                    .Characters(1, FinishPoint).Font.Color = vbRed
                End With
            End If
            If InStr(1, Range("G" & Rw).Value, "U") Then
                StartPoint = Len(Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value) + 2
                FinishPoint = Len(Range("G" & Rw).Value) + StartPoint
                With Range("H" & Rw - 1)
                    .Characters(StartPoint, FinishPoint).Font.Color = vbRed
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next Rw
End Sub
```

Note, that `InStr(1, Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value, "U")` case sensitive. If cell contains `u`, it returns `0`. You can change it to this one: `InStr(1, UCase(Range("G" & Rw - 1).Value), "U")`

Comment: Thanks for your response Simoco. I've adapted your code for my requirements and it runs nicely.

Comment: Evidently I took too long to edit the first comment... I've adapted your code for my requirements and it runs nicely, however the second issue that I thought might come up has eventuated. Once the next iteration of concatenation is done, the red formatting is dropped. As per the numbered steps in my original post, it works for step 1, then drops the red formatting on step 2 and re-applies it to the "7/02/2014 A U" substring only in step 3. I need all substrings with a U to retain the red formatting. Any further advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean, but try my updated answer